# How to put links to modules in side bar in sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am writing documentation of my project using sphinx and I would like to put link to modules in the side bar. I am able to put the links on the front page but not on the side bar.

Code of index.rst

```
.. DashBoard documentation master file, created by
sphinx-quickstart on Tue Dec 12 12:09:02 2017.
You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to DashBoard's documentation!
=====================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
.. toctree:: source/app
.. toctree:: source/server
.. toctree:: source/server_messages

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
```

I want the things written under contents which are modules to appear on the side bar

Comment: Could you show how have you managed to put them on the front page and, if possible, show what have you tried to put them on a side bar? Thanks.

Comment: To put it on the front page I reference to the rst file generated by the autodoc. I want to put this refrence in the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.. DashBoard documentation master file, created by
    sphinx-quickstart on Tue Dec 12 12:09:02 2017.
    You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
    contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to DashBoard's documentation!
=====================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    source/app
    source/server
    source/server_messages

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
```

Whitespace and proper syntax are critical in reStructuredText for properly rendering documentation.